# Does this describe fourier transform correctly?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

*So i saw this paragraph in an article which wasn't really good and was a complete word salad but this one paragraph caught my eye so i asked on Physics Stack Exchange if this paragraph described Fourier Transform accurately and i got an answer saying no. I want to confirm this , so could someone tell me whether this paragraph is wrong?*

**Fourier showed that any three-dimensional pattern can be analyzed into a set of regular, periodic oscillations that differ only in frequency, amplitude, and phase. Specific waveforms can be exact representations, namely Fourier-transforms, of spatio-temporal objects. When a vessel creates waves on the surface of the sea, it creates Fourier-transforms of its impact on the waters of the sea. It is shown [172] that the surface of the sea is surprisingly information-rich (in-formation, see footnote n˚ 23). When its wave-patterns are subjected to mathematical analysis, it discloses in-formation on the passage of ships, e.g. the direction of wind, the effect of shorelines, and other factors. The interfering wave-patterns may be conserved for hours and sometimes for days, after the vessels that created them have passed. Though ultimately they dissipate, eroded by the combined action of gravity, wind, and shorelines, as long as the wave-patterns persist, they provide in-formation on the events that occurred at the sea’s surface. But the waves created by vessels on the surface do more than create in-formation regarding their own motion: they also in-form the motion of other vessels. All vessels that traverse the wake that spreads out behind a given vessel are rocked by those waves; in this sense the motion of the wave-creating vessel is translated into the motion of the wave-rocked vessels. The medium that transmits the effects is the surface of the sea: it interconnects the wave-creating with the wave-rocked vessels. And, as all vessels both create waves and are rocked by them, the sea interconnects the motion of all vessels on its surface.**

I feel that it is wrong but please let me know

Comment: What is wrong about it? I suppose it is a little blithe to say the waves are "Fourier transforms" of the object creating waves. To be more math-y, the linear wave response in the spectral domain will depend on the spectral source function (Fourier transform of the impulse) and also on the dispersive character of the medium (Fourier transform of the homogeneous wave equation). So technically the inverse transform is the convolution of both transforms, and this is only a linearized description.

Comment: @bartholovidius so im like a dummy in this, so does it mean that the wave is like a frequency which if interpreted will give the way the object looks?

Comment: I agree with you, @UnbowedEpicure. I don't think Fourier showed any such thing. First, to nit-pick: water is a non-linear phenomena, and not described by linear decomposition. Fluid flow is certainly not described this way. Bloviate is a word that comes to mind.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Though surface gravity wave analysis is almost universally approached using linear analysis with weak coupling terms, e.g. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112009991820

Comment: @Disintegrating By Parts  Yeah I thought so too

Comment: And, furthermore, Fourier showed no such thing.